# glAccum (blur effect) working with with one graphics card but not the other

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to create a "blur" effect in my OpenGL game, whereby in certain sections I enable the following code and the vision blurs for a bit...

```
if(world->blur) {
    glAccum(GL_MULT, 0.85);
    glAccum(GL_ACCUM, 1- 0.85);
    glAccum(GL_RETURN, 1.0);
    glFlush();
}
```

Which works fine when I am using my laptop's integrated chip, which often results in lower framerate, but if I enable the ATI gpu which gives me faster performance then the effect is not visible...

I am using a fixed-time clock on my game:

```
tickTime += dt;
if(tickTime >= 1/DESIRED_FRAME_RATE) {
    level->update(tickTime);
    world->update(tickTime);
    renderer->drawScene(tickTime);
    tickTime = 0;
}
```

Is there some obvious reason why this happens?

Comment: Interesting...probably an obvious question, but is the driver up to date?

Comment: Show us your context creation code.

Answer (score 3):

Just a suggestion, but did you tink of using Frame Buffer Objects (FBOs) instead of the accumulation buffer? FBOs are far better supported.

The majority of cosumer grade GPU doesn't support accumulation buffers. Your integrated GPU may be a Intel GPU (very likely). If that's a Linux machine you're working on you'll fall into Mesa software fallback. And the fglrx will not give you accumulation buffering at all.

Using a FBO for accumulation blur is straightforward: You need two textures (one render target and a accumulation texture), which alter their function:

1. bind texture A as FBO target
2. render scene
3. bind texture B as FBO target
4. render scene with jitter
5. 1. bind texture A as sampling source
   2. enable blending, glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
   3. set a modulating texture environment or shader
   4. glColor4f(1., 1., 1., 1./N);
   5. glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); glDepthMask(GL_FALSE)l
   6. draw textured quad covering the scene
6. swap textures A<>B
7. repeat steps 3 to 6 N times.

Or instead od accumulation blur use a shader implementing vector blur which is far more efficient.

Comment: Thank you, sounds good, I'll try that and get back with results!

Answer (score 2):

You should check if you get any error code(s) back from OpenGL. Also, you can read out the buffer's precision, if it's 0 the buffer is not available.

Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183179/opengl-glaccum-error-1282-invalid-operation) seems to indicate that many ATi cards lack an accumulation buffer.

Comment: that's probably the reason, I am going to test this on a desktop now and see the result!

Comment: That's quite interesting actually.  I'm guessing with the big move to "all shaders all the time" they decided it wasn't worth their while?

How do older games work?

Op, you may want to check out GLSL (GL Shader Language) to do your blur effects.  The problem (IMO anyways) is that shaders are a whole other bag of worms, especially if you're just starting out.

Here is a nice blog article on a gaussian blur in GLSL
http://callumhay.blogspot.com/2010/09/gaussian-blur-shader-glsl.html